# How to get returned value and verbose stream of function?

Tags: powershell

I have two functions: **Write-Log** and **B**. Function **B** can output messages to Verbose Stream and it return some value. I need to get returned value from function **B** to some variable and pass verbose stream to function **Write-Log** via pipline simultaniously.

I tried to do it by line:

```bsh
$a = B -message "World" -Verbose 4>&1 | Write-Log -LogFilePath "D:\test.log"
```

but it outputs all messages to log file include returned value and variable **$a** is empty

Code of function **Write-Log**:

```bsh
function Write-Log {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter (ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string]$Text, 
        [string]$LogFilePath, 
        [switch]$Silent, 
        [ConsoleColor]$ForegroundColor
    )

    process {
        [string]$MessageWithDate = "$((Get-Date).ToString())  $Text"
        if (-not($Silent)) {
            if($ForegroundColor -eq $null) {
                Write-Host $Text
            } else {
                Write-Host $Text -ForegroundColor $ForegroundColor
            }
        }
        try {
            if(-not (Test-Path($($LogFilePath)))) {
                New-Item -Path $($LogFilePath) -ItemType "file" | Out-Null
            }
            $MessageWithDate | Out-File -filepath $($LogFilePath) -Append -NoClobber
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Error has occurred while writing log note to file $($LogFilePath): $($_ | Select-Object -Property *)" -foregroundcolor red
        }
    }
}
```

Code of function **B**:

```bsh
function B{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        $message
    )

    begin {
        Write-Verbose "[Function B] - Start"
        Write-Verbose "Initial parameters:"
        ($PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose "- $($_.Key) = '$($_.Value)'" })
    }

    process {
        return ("Hello, " + $message)
    }

    end {
        Write-Verbose "[Function B] - End"
    }
}
```

I need to have "Hello, World" in variable $a and something like this in log file:

```
3/30/2019 12:37:35 PM  [Function B] - Start
3/30/2019 12:37:35 PM  Initial parameters:
3/30/2019 12:37:35 PM  - message = 'World'
3/30/2019 12:37:35 PM  - Verbose = 'True'
3/30/2019 12:37:35 PM  [Function B] - End
```

Could you please help me with the problem?

Comment: `. { $a = B -message "World" -Verbose } 4>&1 | Write-Log -LogFilePath "D:\test.log"`

Comment: @PetSerAl, it works as I expected, thank you!